# Black screen when trying to install ubuntu

Tags: installation, screen

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop, booting from a CD. However, when click "install ubuntu" from the grub the screen goes to black.
So far I've tried the following all with no result:

- booting "try ubuntu"
- booting with 'nomodeset'
- booting with 'drm_kms_helper.poll=0'
- removing all usb- and other connections from my laptop before booting

These are all the possibe solutions i have found online so far...

Here are some more specifics:

Ubuntu 12.04

Asus R500V with Windows 8 installed

Nvidia graphics card

Does anybody know what could be the problem?

Comment: As Windows8 is installed is Secure boot enabled?

Comment: Little weird solution but works for me - Just wait for some time and  Press enter key few times . Do this 2-3 times :P

Comment: Have you tried the CD on another computer to make sure it's not damaged in any way? Just try to boot it, and see if it gives a black screen there too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) (Answers there include a number of troubleshooting steps and fixes not listed here; hopefully some may help.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the options `acpi=off` and `noapic`.
If it does not work you should try the text-based installation of the Alternate-CD.
http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/

Comment: This didn´t work. also tried hitting enter a few times with no result...